# Django rest framework and frontend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use Django Rest Framework to create RESTAPI to integrate with the payment gateway API like stripe. For the frontend part I can only see project using React for the frontend. Cant i use Django as a frontend?
Looking for suggestions if i really just need to use React or Vue. Or is it possible to use django as frontend as well.
Looking for your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: You need to use JS to call REST apis asynchronously from the client-side, you can use a framework like React or Vue for this or just vanilla JS. Django doesn't have anything to do with your client-side other than serving HTML/templates and your static files

Comment: If implementing Stripe the only reason to use Django-Rest, you can use Stripe Python Library with Django. You do not need Django-Rest for that. Here is the github repo https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python.

Answer (score 0):

To use Stripe in Django, you may refer to this package https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe which supports Stripe out-of-the box specific for Django

For replacing React with Django for front-end, it is possible and you can use Django template, however, it depends on your use-case.